# Apply changes for bound datagridview back to SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce

So I've been following this great guide for SQL Server CE:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

For WinForms instead of ASP.NET. I've bound my `datagridview` to the local database source and can view my dummy information fine.

The problem is when I'm trying write back to the table or modify an existing cell's contents. I cannot save the changes. How to I write back to the table? Do I need an event after like `CellEndEdit`? Are there some good examples to do this on another site?

The form load event simply contains this to load the `datagridview` so I'm not sure if it's truly "bound."

```
this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDBDataSet2.Products);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow so here we are:
`productsTableAdapter.Update(testDBDataSet2);`

Answer (score 1):

Having just dealt with a similar issue, I've learned a few things. First, the changes you make to the DataGridView aren't committed to the database until the cell is validated. With a data-bound DataGridView, the cells are validated at the row level, and until you change the focus away from the row you're editing, the changes won't be committed unless you use a CellChangeEvent to force the row to be validated similar to the following:

```
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 9 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value is DBNull)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            this.Validate();
        }
    }
```

If you're trying to have the dataGridView show changes you've made to the underlying database, you need to refresh the table adapter, as you've described above. If you do a Fill before you commit the changes though, you'll lose your changes.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you work with development environment. As you are working with SQLCE, you may have created db file in your project. Visual studio will also makes a copy of your db in bin folder. Now what so ever database transactions you make will effect this local database copy which reside in bin folder. So try to attach that bin database with SQL Management studio or visual studio. This will defiantly show your recently inserted data.